# Intersection of arbitrary oscillation

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am looking for a solution to calculate the intersections of arbitrary (harmonic) oscillations. For example Biorythm with constant amplitude and different periods. Especially my problem with oscillations havin different periods and amplitudes.

Comment: Fourier series has summation of infinite sinusoidal components with different amplitudes.

Answer (score 0):

With arbitrary periods and phases, we have
$$\sin(at+b)=\sin(ct+d).$$
Taking the $\arcsin$,
$$at+b=ct+d+2k\pi\text{, or }at+b=\pi-(ct+d)+2k\pi,$$
$$t=\frac{d-b+2k\pi}{a-c}\text{, or }t=\frac{\pi-d-b+2k\pi}{a+c}.$$
In the specific case of physical vs. emotional rythms, $a=2\pi/23,b=0,c=2\pi/28,d=0$, and
$$t=\frac{644k}{5}\text{, or }t=\frac{322(2k+1)}{51}.$$

Comment: In the case that amplitudes are also different, I don't think there is an easy solution. There is one for different amplitudes and equal periods.